# Nexus Nuget Repository List Version Information

Tags: nuget, nexus, nuget-package

I use nexus nuget repository and I want to get my version information list

I use  nuget.exe and get all version information if I not use -allversion point I access latest versions

```
nuget.exe list -Source http://xxxxx/nexus/service/local/nug
et/RepoName/ -allversion
```

But I want to access specific versions,I give the versionnumber and I want get package list which their version number

Is It possible to do something like that

nuget.exe list -Source http://xxxxx/nexus/service/local/nug
    et/RepoName/ -version 1.0.1

and returns 
 A 1.0.1
B 1.0.1 
C 1.0.1 in the repository ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `nuget.exe` supports the `-version` flag:

```
$ nuget.exe list -?
usage: NuGet list [search terms] [options]

Displays a list of packages from a given source. If no sources are specified, all sources defined in %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config are used. If NuGet.config specifies no sources, uses the default NuGet feed.

     Specify optional search terms.

options:

 -Source +                 A list of packages sources to search.
 -Verbose                  Displays a detailed list of information for each package.
 -AllVersions              List all versions of a package. By default, only the latest package version is displayed.
 -Prerelease               Allow prerelease packages to be shown.
 -Help                (?)  help
 -Verbosity                Display this amount of details in the output: normal, quiet, detailed.
 -NonInteractive           Do not prompt for user input or confirmations.
 -ConfigFile               The NuGet configuration file. If not specified, file %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config is used as configuration file.

For more information, visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference
```

But, you could use an OData query against the nuget gallery service to get what you are looking for. e.g.

```
http://xxxx/nexus/service/local/nuget/RepoName/Packages()?$filter=Version%20eq%20'1.0.1'
```

Comment: You are right,I wonder if this is possible but seems it not.So only way to do that use odata and query repository,thanks